# How to add authentication to MongoDB Cluster with Query Router and Config Server

Tags: mongodb, authentication, sharding

I had created MongoDB cluster with one config server (mongod) and one Query Router
(mongos) and two shards (mongod)

I started the Config server without authentication and started Query Router and added the Admin user

Now I can able authenticate Query Router and Config server using admin user, How can add authentication to Shards?

Thanks in advance